# Owl Carousel returning errors with higher version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm trying to install Owl Carousel 2 in my website.I have added following files for owl-carousel.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/owl-carousel.js"defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/owl.carousel.css">
```

Added following function to call Jquery

```
$(".owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        items: 2,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 2],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
        pagination: false,
        rewindNav: false,
        slideBy: 2,
        scrollPerPage: true,
        afterAction: function () {
            if (this.itemsAmount > this.visibleItems.length) {
                $('.next').show();
                $('.prev').show();

                $('.next').removeClass('disabled');
                $('.prev').removeClass('disabled');
                if (this.currentItem == 0) {
                    $('.prev').addClass('disabled');
                }
                if (this.currentItem == this.maximumItem) {
                    $('.next').addClass('disabled');
                }
            } else {
                $('.next').hide();
                $('.prev').hide();
            }
        }
    });

    $(".next").click(function () {
        $(".owl-demo").trigger('owl.next');
    })
    $(".prev").click(function () {
        $(".owl-demo").trigger('owl.prev');
    })
```

Added following HTML code

```
<div class="carousel">
                            <div class="owl-demo owl-carousel">
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="~/Images/slider-img.png" />
                                    <div class="img-title">text will come here</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="~/Images/slider-img.png" />
                                    <div class="img-title">text will come here</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="~/Images/slider-img.png" />
                                    <div class="img-title">text will come here</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="~/Images/slider-img.png" />
                                    <div class="img-title">text will come here</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="customNavigation">
                                <a id="customnavi1" class="btn prev">
                                    <img src="~/lib/images/BackButtonBlack.PNG" />
                                </a>
                                <a id="customnavi2" class="btn next">
                                    <img src="~/lib/images/NextArrowBlack.PNG" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

But still facing follwing issue 
[image]

And I have no idea why it's returning this error.

Comment: Where are you putting owlCarousel code, inside HTML or separate script file. Put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //code });` and then try.

Comment: I have tried both options. problem is I'm using jquery-3.1.1.min.js, if I use lower version of Jquery then carousel working fine. What should I do in this condition

Comment: Which version owlCarousel are you using? I tried (https://jsfiddle.net/qun0kv9n/) with owlCarousel 2 (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html) and it gives no errors. check fiddle and I have used jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Comment: Thanks. Next back is not working in your created fiddle. I am using owlCarousel 2 also.

Comment: Yes, you have to debug that. I can do this once I'll have time. I'll post an answer if you are happy with my solution.

Comment: yes sure. Please help me in next back navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, working **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qun0kv9n/1/)** demo. As you wanted.

```
$(".next").click(function () {
    $(".owl-next").trigger('click');
})
$(".prev").click(function () {
     $(".owl-prev").trigger('click');
});
```